# How to remove extra, default padding in RecycleView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontally ordered `RecycleView` and I want to remove extra empty space between elements. How? The structure of the `RecycleView` is like below.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/userSettingList"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
```

And here is the row item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="60dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:padding="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: May be you can remove the margin given to your `row_item`.

Comment: Can you provide your  row item xml ??

Comment: relative layout is 70dp and imageview 66dp. so there will be a gap of 4dp. so u should listen to @Moulesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Relative layout in your row item to wrap content  i mean android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"